# Create an instance of an object from a String in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

How would I do the Dart equivalent of this Java code?

```java
Class<?> c = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass");
Constructor<?> cons = c.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = cons.newInstance("MyAttributeValue");
```

(From Jeff Gardner)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dart code:

```dart
ClassMirror c = reflectClass(MyClass);
InstanceMirror im = c.newInstance(const Symbol(''), ['MyAttributeValue']);
var o = im.reflectee;
```

Learn more from this doc: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/

(From Gilad Bracha)

Comment: Both 'first' and 'classes' properties are not on LibraryMirror any more (I'm using 30188). How would you do this with Dart v1?

Answer (score 0):

Using [built_mirrors](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_mirrors) you can do it next way:

```
library my_lib;

import 'package:built_mirrors/built_mirrors.dart';

part 'my_lib.g.dart';

@reflectable
class MyClass {

  String myAttribute;

  MyClass(this.myAttribute);
}

main() {
  _initMirrors();

  ClassMirror cm = reflectType(MyClass);

  var o = cm.constructors[''](['MyAttributeValue']);

  print("o.myAttribute: ${o.myattribute}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue that has plagued me until I figured that I could implement a crude **from** method to handle the conversion of *encoded Json Objects/strings* or *Dart Maps* to the desired class.

Below is a simple example that also handles nulls and accepts JSON (*as the* **string** *parameter*)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class PaymentDetail
{
  String AccountNumber;
  double Amount;
  int ChargeTypeID;
  String CustomerNames;

  PaymentDetail({
    this.AccountNumber,
    this.Amount,
    this.ChargeTypeID,
    this.CustomerNames
  });

  PaymentDetail from ({ string : String, object : Map  }) {
     var map   = (object==null) ? (string==null) ? Map() : json.decode(string) : (object==null) ? Map() : object;
     return new PaymentDetail(
        AccountNumber             : map["AccountNumber"] as String,
        Amount                    : map["Amount"] as double,
        ChargeTypeID              : map["ChargeTypeID"] as int,
        CustomerNames             : map["CustomerNames"] as String
     );
  }

}
```

Below is it's implementation

```
 PaymentDetail payDetail =  new PaymentDetail().from(object: new Map());

 PaymentDetail otherPayDetail =  new PaymentDetail().from(object: {"AccountNumber": "1234", "Amount": 567.2980908});
```

Once again, this is simplistic and tedious to clone throughout the project but it works for simple cases.